# Stripe::AuthenticationError No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, heroku, stripe-payments

UPDATE:
I set the publishable key directly inline like so: `Stripe.setPublishableKey("pk_live_*****");`
and it works!!
The problem is it is not properly configuring with `ENV['stripe_publishable_key']`.

ORIGINAL POST:

I am using the koudoku gem for Stripe. Everything works fine locally, but when I push to heroku, I am getting the error:

`Stripe::AuthenticationError (No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>".`

Even though it sets the publishable key in development. Also, if I run heroku config, I see the keys there.

What is happening here? Why is it not setting the key??

application.yml

```
development:
  stripe_api_key: 'sk_test_***'
  stripe_publishable_key: 'pk_test_***'

production:
  stripe_api_key: 'sk_live_***'
  stripe_publishable_key: 'pk_live_***'
```

config/initializers/koudoku.rb

```
Koudoku.setup do |config|
  config.subscriptions_owned_by = :user
  config.stripe_publishable_key = ENV['stripe_publishable_key']
  config.stripe_secret_key = ENV['stripe_api_key']

  Stripe.api_version = '2015-01-11' #Making sure the API version used is compatible.
  # config.prorate = false # Default is true, set to false to disable prorating subscriptions
  # config.free_trial_length = 30

  # Specify layout you want to use for the subscription pages, default is application
  config.layout = 'application'

  # you can subscribe to additional webhooks here
  # we use stripe_event under the hood and you can subscribe using the 
  # stripe_event syntax on the config object: 
  # config.subscribe 'charge.failed', Koudoku::ChargeFailed

end
```

_card.html.erb

```
<div class="padding_page">
  <div class="wrapper_form_dark wrapper_form_sign_on">

<%# content_for :koudoku do %>

<%# end %>

<%= form_for @subscription, url: url, html: {id: 'payment-form', class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>

  <fieldset>
<div class="form_section">
    <legend class="page_title">Update Payment Info</legend>



      <label class="label_standard">Card Number</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number input_standard"/>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form_section">
      <label class="label_standard">Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" size="2" class="card-expiry-month input_mini"/>
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="4" class="card-expiry-year input_mini"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form_section">
      <label class="label_standard">CVC</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc input_mini"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-error payment-errors red"></div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>

  </fieldset>

  <div class="form_section">
    <div class="actions">
      <% if Koudoku.free_trial? %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn_primary submit-button">Save Billing Information</button>
      <% else %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn_primary_large submit-button">Update Card Information</button>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", owner_subscriptions_path(@owner), class: 'btn red' %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // All this code taken from Stripe's own examples at:
  // https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms .

  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

      if (response.error) {
          // show the errors on the form
          $(".payment-errors").text(response.error.message).show();
          $(".submit-button").removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
          var form$ = $("#payment-form");
          // token contains id, last4, and card type
          // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
          form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='subscription[credit_card_token]' value='" + response['id'] + "'/>");
          form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='subscription[last_four]' value='" + response['last4'] + "'/>");
          form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='subscription[card_type]' value='" + response['card_type'] + "'/>");
          // and submit
          form$.get(0).submit();
      }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {



    Stripe.setPublishableKey("<%= Koudoku.stripe_publishable_key %>");

    // By default, don't show errors.
    $(".payment-errors").hide()

    $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {

      // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");

      Stripe.createToken({
          number: $('.card-number').val(),
          cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
          exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
          exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
      }, stripeResponseHandler);

      // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

UPDATE:
I see the log of the post in stripe's logs, and it has a response of 200...

```
{
  "card": {
    "number": "************5458",
    "cvc": "***",
    "exp_month": "11",
    "exp_year": "2019"
  },
  "key": "pk_live_***",
  "payment_user_agent": "stripe.js/81eca10",
  "callback": "sjsonp1484600040115",
  "_method": "POST",
  "_accept_language": "en-US"
}
```

but the app is still throwing the same error of no key. Hopefully this helps?

Comment: When you find an answer to your own question, you are allowed and encouraged to add it as an official answer.  And, if your own answer is the best answer, you can award it the checkmark.  You can (and should, I think) edit your question to remove the answer at the top and add it as regular... well, answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've often found a need to run `spring stop` in terminal in order for my application to pick up changes to environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

just restarting the local server worked for me